# Joomla 3.0 Plugin Update Error

Tags: plugins, joomla

I am having a problem updating a plugin in Joomla 3.0 I have the T3 plugin that needs to be updated and when I go to update it I get the error:

An error has occured.
Copy file failed.

I went and checked on all my warnings and I have none. I also checked the directory permissions and all the folders are writeable.

Any ideas on what could be done to fix the updating error?

Comment: Have you checked with the T3 developer?

Comment: I checked their website and the version listed on the site is 1.2.1 but Joomla says there is an update available to 1.2.2